# Node running migration timeouts

Tags: javascript, node.js, knex.js

I am running migrations in Node and it timeouts with this error:

`Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.`

This is my code

```
const myList = {
// list of commands
}
exports.up = async (knex) => {
     await Object.values(myList).reduce(async (prev, sp) => {
        await prev;
        return knex.schema.raw(sp);
    }, Promise.resolve());
};
```

As I can see here, I am resolving a Promise as it is suggested. Not sure how should I change this?

Comment: I believe that the `await` keyword has already resolved the Promise so you don't really need the `resolve` parameter out there.

Comment: BTW, if your question is about a particular framework, in this case `knex`, make sure that you add the associated tag to make it clearer.

Comment: How/where are you calling the exported function?

Comment: How long does your migration take? How many commands are there? Maybe your database is just slow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return the promise chain, e.g.

```
exports.up = (knex) => 
    Object.values(myList).reduce((prev, sp) =>
        prev.then(() => knex.schema.raw(sp)), Promise.resolve()
    );
```

or, if you prefer, the longer version:

```
exports.up = (knex) => {
    return Object.values(myList).reduce((prev, sp) => {
        return prev.then(() => knex.schema.raw(sp));
    }, Promise.resolve());
};
```